# Exibição do campo data

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma data no formato americado yyyy-mm-dd e gostaria de colocar no formato brasileiro dd-mm-yyyy porém não quero fazer como conversão to_char. Preciso que continue com o formato date pois precisarei fazer filtros com intervalo de data e como string o filtro não funciona. Poir isso a necessidade de trocar a posição da data, mas permanecendo o tipo date.

BANCO POSTGRES

Comment: Qual o seu banco sql server?

Comment: Então, o banco que utilizo é o Postgres

Comment: acredito que deveria fazer o inverso então, passar o filtro informado para data, ex: `to_date('16012018', 'ddMMyyyy')` o formato aplicado pelo banco é atribuído pelas configurações de culture, e é indiferente na comparação

Comment: Você está confundindo o formato de armazenamento de uma campo do tipo date com o formato de exibição. A resposta do Rovann está correta, se não deu certo foi porque você aplicou erroneamente.

Comment: Um detalhe: o formato de data yyyy-mm-dd é o formato ISO, o formato americano é mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigada gente!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar uma variável de ambiente chamada [`DATESTYLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) para o estilo [`GERMAN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT-TABLE):

```
SET DATESTYLE = 'GERMAN';
```

Testando:

```
SELECT current_date;
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nossa! Farei isso!!! Obrigada!!! :)